# jsoup getting html title from loop

Tags: android

here is my code i tried many ways cant seem to get it right i have tried many ways and all the time its not extracting the data i want just null output

```
html code
    <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a name="19110810"></a>
                        <span id="MasterPage1_MainContent__ctlResultsFlatTrovix_rptResults__ctl3_lblDate">05/09/2015</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>


                    </td>
                            <td><a id="MasterPage1_MainContent__ctlResultsFlatTrovix_rptResults__ctl3_lnkTitle" title="" href="http://xxxx/GetJob.ashx?JobID=19110810&amp;JobTitle=Factory%20Manager&amp;rad=20&amp;rad_units=miles&amp;pp=25&amp;sort=rv.dt.di&amp;vw=b&amp;re=134&amp;setype=2&amp;tjt=factory&amp;where=oldham&amp;pg=1&amp;AVSDM=2015-09-05T01%3a03%3a00-05%3a00">Factory Manager</a></td>
                            <td><span id="MasterPage1_MainContent__ctlResultsFlatTrovix_rptResults__ctl3_lblCompany">CV Library</span></td>
                            <td>
                        <span id="MasterPage1_MainContent__ctlResultsFlatTrovix_rptResults__ctl3_lblArea">NW-Oldham</span>
                        <span id="MasterPage1_MainContent__ctlResultsFlatTrovix_rptResults__ctl3_lblCity"></span>
                    </td>
                        </tr>
```

code from android below

```
htmlDocument = Jsoup.connect(urll).timeout(10 * 1000).get();
                //Elements hrefElements = htmlDocument.select("div.listing-content");
                Elements hrefElements = htmlDocument.select("th[class=MasterPage1_MainContent__ctlResultsFlatTrovix_rptResults__ctl0_msgJobTitle]");
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(urll).timeout(10 * 1000).get();
    for (Element table : doc.select("table[class=JSresults]")) {
                                for (Element row : doc.select("table[class=JSresults]")) {
                                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                    String[] titlee = new String[hrefElements.size()];

                                    ArrayList products = new ArrayList();

                                    for (int i = 0; i < hrefElements.size(); i++) {
            //imgg[i] = hrefElements.get(i).getElementsByAttribute("src").after("div[class=listing-content]").attr("src");

                                        titlee[i] = hrefElements.get(i).getElementsByAttribute("a").after("th[class=cssStretch35]").attr("title");
            }
```

am trying to extract the data below from the html code i cannot seem to get it to work.
05/09/2015
title Factory Manager
CV Library
NW-Oldham
href link

Answer (score 0):

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
String title = doc.title();
```

Doesnt work?

Comment: it may work not sure but what about the rest of the values then?

Comment: this is why am trying to get the value using  titlee[i] = hrefElements.get(i).getElementsByAttribute("a").after("th[class=cssStretch35]").attr("title"); not working am trying alot